# Ubuntu System Files Upgrading Process Issue

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I use Ubuntu-Studio 20.04.2 LTS inside 2 desktop PCs and 1 laptop PC.

Each time there is an Ubuntu "core" files upgrading (***linux-image-5.4.0-xx-lowlatency*** and others), the upgrading process tells me that the oldest files were erased.

But... It is not a reality.

If I use the command `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-5.4.0-xx-lowlatency` (where xx is the chronological oldest number of those files), I can clearly see that file is still present in my HDD.

The same with the file ***linux-modules-5.4.0-xx-lowlatency***.

I don't have problems to erase it manually, because I know how to do it.

But... I'm thinking about people who doesn't know about this "cryptic" part of the system... From time to time, that HDD could become full with all those files.

I wonder if there is a way to avoid this.

Or... Maybe, I missed something in the way? ???

Is there a way to automatically erase all those files **inside** de upgrading process? ???

Comment: Files that are automatically installed will be removed by 'auto' commands (eg. `apt autoremove`) when safe to do so, however if you installed a package manually (even a `install --reinstall`) then it's set to manual install and will not be touched by 'auto' remove/clean commands, it'll require the user to manually remove it just as it was the user who manually installed it.   I don't know if this is your issue (sorry I don't understand that), but it may help you to understand you're not describing all the processes involved.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure if your words are directly related with the issue I wrote. I'm talking about the automatic upgrade process. Nothing in that process is directly controlled by the user, and/or superuser. BTW, Thanks a lot for your words.